# In reputation history, a downvote on a removed question is clickable

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, reputation-history

Today a question I asked was removed shortly after a downvote. An hour later, [my reputation history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165455/aaron-bertrand?tab=reputation) still shows the removed and downvote impact to my reputation. Since the post was removed, the link is not clickable next to the "removed" entry. But I can click on the "downvote" entry and get taken to the 404 waffle iron. Shouldn't the downvote entry also use the same status to determine that the link shouldn't be clickable, instead of causing unnecessary traffic by offering me to click on something it knows doesn't exist?

> [image]